# .desktop file appears to run a .sh file executable, but doesn't complete

Tags: 14.04, mount, scripts, .desktop, .sh

I hope I have done my due diligence in searching previous posts. I am new to ubuntu (14.04), and still learning. I wasn't able to find this problem previously asked.

I have created a .sh file (/home/Desktop/mountServer.sh) and set properties->Execute to allow executing file as program. If I run this .sh from the terminal manually using `cd Desktop/`, and`./mountServer.sh` it works perfectly. When I run the .desktop file 'Mount Server.desktop', it opens the terminal as instructed and prompts me for my password. But then, nothing happens. It doesn't mount my disk. No error message.

mountServer.desktop code :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Mount Server
Comment=Mounts the Server 1.5 from Apple Airport Extreme
Exec=sudo /home/Desktop/mountServer.sh
Icon=/paht/to/icon.png
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

mountServer.sh code:

```
sudo mount -t cifs "//10.0.1.1/The Server 1.5" -o username=myusername,password=pwhere,sec=ntlm ~/capsule
```

Answer (score 1):

The line seems to be wrong, your Desktop folder isn't in `/home`

```
Exec=sudo /home/Desktop/mountServer.sh
```

and there is no need to use `sudo` twice, once in you script and once in your desktop file.

Use

```
Exec=/home/your_username/Desktop/mountServer.sh
```

instead, replace `your_username` with your username (the output of `echo $USER`)

And you should use

```
$HOME/capsule
```

instead of

```
~/capsule
```

in your script.

---

The best solution for you is, install `gksu` via

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

A desktop file like this, replace `your_username` with your username (the output of `echo $USER`)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Mount Server
Comment=Mounts the Server 1.5 from Apple Airport Extreme
Exec=gksu /home/your_username/Desktop/mountServer.sh
Icon=/paht/to/icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

and a script like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mount -t cifs "//10.0.1.1/The Server 1.5" -o username=myusername,password=pwhere,sec=ntlm "$HOME"/capsule
```

With this solution you have a graphically password prompt, no unneeded terminal and if you want to start your script directly in a terminal you can use

```
sudo ~/Desktop/mountServer.sh
```

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough reply! gksu makes the password prompt much nicer. I fixed the "$HOME" problem in the script as well as the path issue in the .desktop file. Unfortunately, something is still amiss.

If I double-click the .desktop file, it prompts me for a password, but does not actually succeed in mounting the disk. Again, there is no error message or indication of failure other than the disk isn't mounted.

On the other hand, if I run from the terminal  'sudo ~/Desktop/mountServer.sh' as you indicated, the server mounts instantly.

Comment: And what you mean with "something" :)

Comment: You're quick! I accidentally hit enter instead of shift+enter before I had finished my message. It's edited now with more detail

Comment: And you have `your_username` replaced with your real username?

Comment: Yes, I do. I copied the path directly from nautilus to make sure I didn't make any mistakes.

Comment: Here is the current mountServer.desktop file:   
                                          `[Desktop Entry]
Name=Mount Server
Comment=Mounts the Server 1.5 from Apple Airport Extreme
Exec=gksu /home/sumner/Desktop/mountServer.sh
Icon=home/sumner/logo-128x128.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application`                                  
Here is the current mountServer.sh:
                                             `#!/usr/bin/env bash
mount -t cifs "//10.0.1.1/The Server 1.5" -o username=sumner,password=pwd,sec=ntlm "$HOME"/capsule`  where pwd is replaced by my password, of course.